# How do I compare values in parallel arrays to eliminate duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a program to deal 5 random cards from a deck of cards while ensuring there are no duplicates dealt, using parallel arrays only. This is what I have so far.

```
int [] notSuit = {1, 2, 3, 4};
String [] copySuit = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};

int [] notValue = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}; 
String [] copyValue = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};

String [] verifiedCards = new String[5];

int [] suit = new int[5];
int [] value = new int[5];

int randSuit;
int randVal;
for (int i = 0; i < suit.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
        randSuit = rand.nextInt(notSuit.length);
        randVal = rand.nextInt(notValue.length);

        suit[i] = notSuit[randSuit];
        value[i] = notValue[randVal];

        verifiedCards[i] = copyValue[randVal] + " of " + copySuit[randSuit]; // stores cards in english
    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < suit.length; x++) {
    for (int c = 1; c < suit.length; c++) {
        if ((suit[x] == suit[c]) && (value[x] == suit[c])) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate Spotted!");
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the bottom nested for loop to try to iterate through the array to find duplicates and denote them by printing out "Duplicate Spotted".  The problem is, even when there is a duplicate card dealt the if statement never evaluates to true, and so I can't go about replacing the duplicate card.

Answer (score 2):

The logic behind the code looks fine. I think you simply made a little typo in the latter for loop. I think the condition in the if statement should read

```
(suit[x] == suit[c]) && (value[x] == value[c])
```

instead of

```
(suit[x] == suit[c]) && (value[x] == suit[c])
```

Comment: Some of the pairs of cards are being checked more than once. The inner loop should probably start at `x+1`, and the outer loop should end at `x < length - 1`. This will also avoid `x == c` which your code currently claims is a duplicate, but is actually only one card (compared to itself).